# How to put many recyclerview in a fragment

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Hope you are having happy coding ! I have being trying to add two recycler view to my HomeFragment the second one (category_recyclerView) doesn't load any data dunno why! I have tried multiple times to change the adapter and rewrite the code again, I don't see the error so please I need your help thanks!

```
recyclerViewCategory = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_category);
    recyclerViewCategory.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager1;
    layoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerViewCategory.setLayoutManager(layoutManager1);
```

this the adapter

```
 FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Products> options1 = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Products>()
            .setQuery(ProductsRef, Products.class)
            .build();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, CategoryViewHolder> adapter1 = new
            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, CategoryViewHolder>(options1) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Products model) {
                    Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.imageCircleCategory);
                    holder.categoryName.setText(model.getCategory());
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_layout, parent, false);
            CategoryViewHolder holder = new CategoryViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
        }
    };
    recyclerViewCategory.setAdapter(adapter1);
    adapter1.startListening();
```

this is my XML recyclerview (both)

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_category"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    />
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_menu1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_category"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    app:spanCount="2"
    />
```

the both are in the same fragment the first Recycler_menu1 works fine but i don't see why the other doesn't

this is the update of the XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/category_linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/categories"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_category"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/category_linear2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Products"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_menu1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        app:spanCount="2"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove this line  `recyclerViewCategory.setHasFixedSize(true);`?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for view types

Answer (score 0):

in the XML, recycler_menu1 has the property `android:layout_height="match_parent"`
this can cause the problem. the other recyclerView can be hidden under this one.

Comment: i have succeed to show the both recyclers after i put them in LinyearLayout, but whenever i switch between the fragments the recycler with a layout_height wrap_content disappears, so strange i'm trying to find the problem with plying between wrap content and match parent in the linyear Layout,